# Error: 2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oracle10g

I want to build a connection and to connect sql server to php but it gives this error on

the browser. i want to build at local host.

kindly help.

if question doesnt make a sense than dnt vote it down please.

```
 <?php



 $conn = oci_connect("system","password","localhost/xe");



 $username = $_POST["username"];



 $password = $_POST["password"];



  $sql = oci_parse($conn,"Select * from login where username = '$username' and password = 


  '$password'");


  oci_execute($sql);




  $nrows = oci_fetch_all($sql , $res);




  if($nrows > 0)



{



    echo "Login Successfull";



  }
else







{


    echo "Username and password is incorrect";



}



   ?>
```

Comment: Please clarify the question. Its a little hard to understand if the problem is with mamp (or whatever you are using) or the php.

Comment: I m using oracle 10 g and want to retrive queries on php .
using Zend and apachee

Comment: Ok I see you want to set up a database connection to the oracle 10g with php?

Comment: @user2205394: do not put code in the comments. Edit your question instead.

Comment: IS it sql or oracle? First the question said oracle then now sql. What is it?

Comment: it is oracle.
some one said u should use oracle code i said i have used then he asked me too put it on the code section so i did.
kindly vote up not vote down
thankx

Comment: You can´t expect up votes when the question is not stated in an understandable manner. You get up votes for good questions and down votes for bad once.

Answer (score 2):

To connect to an oracle database with php (PDO) do the following.

```
<?php
try {
$dbh = new PDO("OCI:", "username", "password")
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

This example might be easier to understand:
Accounts = database name "charset=utf-8"=used for most languages, username and password = root (in most cases on localhost).

```
<?php
try {
$dbh = new PDO("OCI:dbname=accounts;charset=UTF-8", "username", "password");
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{     echo $e->getMessage();     } ?>
```

Since you changed the question to SQL I guess I can add some code to. The above answer is for oracle, but if you want to connect to SQL do the following.

```
<?php

$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

try {
   $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=mysql", $username, $password);
   echo 'Connected to database';
   }
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

If you still have not solved the problem I would suggest going to: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

Please close or remove the question, depending if you are happy with the answers or don´t feel you got the answers you where looking for.

Comment: it gives internal server error

Comment: @user2205394: check the Apache error logs and let us know what you find.

Comment: i coulnt find anything

Comment: There could be something wrong with your "localhost client" which one are you using? Wamp?

Comment: it gives couldnot find driver

Comment: Well what program can not find driver? In any case would my recommendation be to re-install it and start over. Since it seems like it is corrupt.

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
this error it gave when i tried last code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple: you are using the `mysql_` functions to connect to Oracle. You can't do that.

Maybe this will get you started: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3763916/Intro-to-PHP--Oracle.htm